# Grouped bar chart from counter

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Struggling to understand how to properly generate a (grouped) bar chart like the one in [this example](https://play.grafana.org/d/ktMs4D6Mk/5-bar-charts-and-pie-charts?orgId=1&tab=query):

[image]

My Prometheus metrics are like this:

```
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse0", sellable="false"} 0
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse0", sellable="true"} 2
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse0", sellable="false"} 0
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse0", sellable="true"} 43
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse1", sellable="false"} 100
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse1", sellable="true"} 21
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse1", sellable="false"} 2
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse1", sellable="true"} 15
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse2", sellable="false"} 1
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse2", sellable="true"} 8
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse2", sellable="false"} 22
articles_sellable_total{location="Warehouse2", sellable="true"} 11
```

And so, I've been following the docs, then trying to group like

```
sum by (location, sellable) (articles_sellable_total{})
```

but in the Table view in Grafana it gives me something like

```
Time           {location="Warehouse0", sellable="false"}
2024-03-25 14:19:00   0
2024-03-25 14:19:30   0
2024-03-25 14:20:00   0
2024-03-25 14:20:30   0
```

also variants like `count by (location, sellable) (articles_sellable_total{})` and `sum by (location) (articles_sellable_total{sellable="true"}) + (articles_sellable_total{sellable="false"})`

So either the location is not persisted, or the table view gives nonsense, or the x-axis is just messed up.

Answer (score 1):

*Bar chart* panel expects data in format

| Categories | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category1 | value | value |
| Category2 | value | value |
| Category3 | value | value |

Your initial query is just fine in terms of providing needed data. But it requires some massaging to put it into expected format.

First, to leave only latest values and present them in an easier form for following steps change query options to *Format*: **Table**, *Type*: **Instant** (Options block under query editor).

Then to "transpose" table into expected format add Transformation *Grouping to Matrix* with *Column* set to `sellable`, *Row* to `location`, and *Cell value* left as `Value`.

After that in Table view you should see something like

| location\sellable | true | false |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Warehouse0 | 45 | 0 |
| Warehouse1 | 36 | 102 |
| Warehouse2 | 19 | 23 |

And bar chart view should present you groups of bars per `location`, with two bars in each group `true` and `false`. If you want goupping to happen the other way around, you can switch places for *Row* and *Column* options in transformation.